# Change URL site links

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

On my site I have links like that  http://example.com/news/view/1183 , I want to modify them to http://example.com/rozvagy/1183 , where 1183 is id and it always change, how can I do that by modify .htaccess ?

I have tried this,

```
RewriteRule ^rozvagy/([0-9]+) /news/view/$1 [L]
```

Comment: What have you even tried before asking for help?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: RewriteRule ^rozvagy/([0-9]+) /news/view/$1 [L] but it don"t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^rozvagy/([^/]+) /news/view/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Please let me know if you have any query.